# Does Bi-Intuitionistic Logic turn Classical in sufficiently strong first-order theories?

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic

Bi-Intuitionistic Logic adds to Intuitionistic Logic a binary connective $←$ known as co-implication or subtraction. A weak negation $\sim A$ is defined for Bi-Intuitionistic Logic as $\top ← A$; Bi-Intuitionistic Logic proves $\sim A \lor A$ for any wff $A$.

It is known that a variety of basic results in set theory and arithmetic imply the full Classical Law of the Excluded Middle, including the well-ordering of the naturals. Supposing someone were to use Bi-Intuitionistic Logic as a basis for a theory like $PA$ or $ZF(C)$, would results like $\sim A \lor A$ lead to a collapse of the two negations down to just Classical negation? I know that in pretty much any theory of arithmetic, the Classical LEM is equivalent to the well-ordering of the naturals. Is a weaker LEM strong enough to prove a result that would turn the whole thing Classical?

Answer (score 2):

Modulo the caveat that you already have to make some concessions from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to adapt it to intuitionistic logic, no. Bi-intuitionistic logic is conservative over intuitionistic logic, so while it may have use in elucidating the symmetry that classical logic collapses, it will not induce that collapse in and of itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m still a bit in the dark as to how Bi-Intuitionistic Logic invalidates say Diaconescu’s theorem or the proof of LEM from the well-ordering of the naturals. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @PW_246 It doesn't. That's one of the concessions, even for plain intuitionistic logic. Full choice has to go (although there are very, very strong intuitionistic choice principles). The well-ordering principle is simply not true intuitionistically. Only decidable subsets of the naturals have a least element.

Comment: Ok, so full ZFC is clearly off the table. Regarding the well-ordering of the naturals, can’t I use the fact that $A \lor \sim A$ holds for the LEM $\implies$ well-ordering of the naturals part of the proof, and then use the well-ordering of the naturals to prove the full Classical LEM?

Comment: @PW_246 Be careful of lookalikes in bi-intuitionistic logic. $A\vee{\sim}A$ should be interpreted "$A$ is provable, or the negation of $A$ is irrefutable." It's not quite an excluded middle, but rather a sort of dual to non-contradiction: You might be able to prove $A$, you might be able to refute $A$, you might not be able to do either, but you're never going to get that $A$ has to be a secret third thing.

Comment: That’s not exactly what I was getting at. My main point is that it seems the well-ordering of the naturals follows from the fact that we have a non-constructive disjunction for an arbitrary formula $A$, and once the well-ordering of the naturals is proven, the full LEM follows.

Comment: @PW_246 $A\vee{\sim}A$ is not a non-constructive disjunction for $A$. It only looks like one. The dual of those lines of reasoning prove ${\sim}\text{well-ordering}$, but in general you can't do anything useful with ${\sim}A$ in positive intuitionistic logic.